# Update: Issue connecting to PostgreSQL database using ipython-sql (psycopg2==2.9.3, sqlalchemy==2.0.2, ipython-sql==0.3.9, postgres==15.3)

Tags: python, postgresql, jupyter-lab

I am trying to connect to an existing PostgreSQL database. I am able to connect using the `psql` command-line interface, as well as pgAdmin. However, when I try to connect a python environment (JupyterLab and DataSpell), I am unable to connect.

Version Information:

- psycopg2 version: 2.9.3
- sqlalchemy version: 2.0.2
- ipython-sql version: 0.3.9
- postgres version: 15.3

---

```py
%load_ext sql

%env DATABASE_URL=postgresql://retail_user:retail@localhost/retail_db

%%sql
SELECT * FROM orders LIMIT 10
```

The above code outputs:

__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'bind'
Connection info needed in SQLAlchemy format, example: **postgresql://username:password@hostname/dbname** or an existing connection: dict_keys([])

---

After some investigation, I discovered that downgrading SQLAlchemy to version 1.4.22 resolved this issue.

Comment: Are you using [ipython-sql](https://github.com/catherinedevlin/ipython-sql) or [JupySQL](https://github.com/ploomber/jupysql).  If the latter look at [Db connection](https://jupysql.ploomber.io/en/latest/connecting.html) , in particular `from os import  environ ... environ["DATABASE_URL"] = f"postgresql://user:{password}@localhost/database"` from the section *Connecting via an environment variable*.

Comment: I'm using ipython-sql. I've tried connecting with the psycopg2 driver with no avail.

Comment: 1) Follow the instructions here [ipython sql](https://github.com/catherinedevlin/ipython-sql) for making a connection. FYI, they don't include `env`. 2) Add the `psycopg2` code you tried and the error message as **text** update to your question. 3) Add version information for ipython-sql, Postgres, SQLAlchemy and psycopg2 as update to question.

Comment: After following your advice and carefully reviewing the instructions for establishing a connection using ipython-sql, I realized that the version of SQLAlchemy I was using (2.0.2) was causing the problem. Following your suggestion, I downgraded to SQLAlchemy version 1.4.22, and that resolved the issue completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was not due to incorrect connection details, but rather a compatibility issue between the versions of SQLAlchemy and ipython-sql I was using. I was initially using SQLAlchemy version 2.0.2, which resulted in this error.

To resolve the issue, I downgraded SQLAlchemy to version 1.4.22. After making this change, the connection worked as expected and I was able to execute SQL queries using ipython-sql without encountering the error.

For those who might face a similar problem:

- Check the versions of SQLAlchemy and ipython-sql you are using.
- If you are using a version of SQLAlchemy higher than 1.4.22, consider downgrading it to version 1.4.22.
- Re-run your code after the downgrade to confirm that the issue is resolved.

Thank you to [Adrian Klaver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7070613/adrian-klaver) for suggesting the steps that ultimately led to the solution.

Comment: Per [ipython-sql](https://github.com/catherinedevlin/ipython-sql): *IPython-SQL's functionality and maintenance have been eclipsed by JupySQL, a fork maintained and developed by the Ploomber team. Future work will be directed into JupySQL - please file issues there, as well!*. I would think about migrating to [JupySQL](https://github.com/ploomber/jupysql).